# Running Stardog on Heroku

Tags: heroku, stardog

I'm doing research about how to run Stardog on Heroku but there is no trace.

The most related info is something about running Stardog.js (Stardog.rb, and other languages). This repositories are useful to connect to with an existent Stardog server and that isn't what I'm looking for.

So, is it possible to run a Stardog server on Heroku? Is there anyone  experienced in?

Comment: Hello. I'm trying the same thing. Did you figure it out ? Thanks. Clément

Comment: I can't help you out here, I changed my mind. Sorry

Comment: So what have you done instead of that solution ?

Comment: Dedicated server